# C++20 requires expression does not catch static_assert

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, c++-concepts, type-constraints

I was really excited when I first heard about C++20 constraints and concepts, and so far I've been having a lot of fun testing them out. Recently, I wanted to see if it's possible to use C++20 concepts to test the constraints of classes or functions. For example:

```cpp
template <int N>
requires (N > 0)
class MyArray { ... };

template <int N>
concept my_array_compiles = requires {
  typename MyArray<N>;
};

my_array_compiles<1>;  // true
my_array_compiles<0>;  // false
```

At first I didn't have any issues, but I encountered a case where static_assert in a dependent function prevents compilation, even though it appears in a requires expression. Here is an example that illustrates this:

```cpp
template <bool b>
requires b
struct TestA {
  void foo() {}
};

template <bool b>
struct TestB {
  static_assert(b);
  void foo() {}
};

template <template<bool> class T, bool b>
concept can_foo = requires (T<b> test) {
  test.foo();
};

can_foo<TestA, true>;   // true
can_foo<TestA, false>;  // false
can_foo<TestB, true>;   // true
// can_foo<TestB, false>; does not compile
```

TestA and TestB should work similarly for most use cases (although I found that TestB<false> can be used as a type as long as it isn't instantiated or dereferenced). However, my expectation was that a failed static_assert within a requires expression would cause it to evaluate to false instead. This is especially important for using library code that still uses static_assert. For example, std::tuple_element:

```cpp
template <class T>
concept has_element_0 = requires {
    typename tuple_element_t<0, T>;
};

has_element_0<tuple<int>>;  // true
// has_element_0<tuple<>>; does not compile
```

When I pass in an empty tuple to the above concept, I get the error `static_assert failed due to requirement '0UL < sizeof...(_Types)' "tuple_element index out of range"`. I've tested this on g++ 10.3.0 and clang 12.0.5. I was able to work around this issue by providing a wrapper that uses constraints, but it somewhat defeats the purpose since I am essentially preventing the compiler from seeing the static_assert by enforcing the same condition at a higher level.

```cpp
template <size_t I, class T>
requires (I >= 0) && (I < tuple_size_v<T>)
using Type = tuple_element_t<I, T>;

template <class T>
concept has_element_0 = requires {
    typename Type<0, T>;
};

has_element_0<tuple<int>>;  // true
has_element_0<tuple<>>;     // false
```

And it doesn't always work depending on how std::tuple_element is used:

```cpp
template <size_t I, class T>
requires (I >= 0) && (I < tuple_size_v<T>)
tuple_element_t<I, T> myGet(const T& tup) {
    return get<I>(tup);
}

template <class T>
concept has_element_0 = requires (T tup) {
    myGet<0>(tup);
};

has_element_0<tuple<int>>;  // true
// has_element_0<tuple<>>; does not compile
```

So ultimately my questions are: is this expected behavior that requires expressions don't take static_assert into account? If so, what was the reason for that design? And finally, is there a better way to accomplish my goal on classes with static_assert without using the above workaround?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Like in [sfinae](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae), only errors in the "immediate context" are catched. Presumably to avoid making the checks too expensive on huge templates.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I believe your answer is correct, but where in the standard does it say that?

Comment: @BrianBi http://eel.is/c++draft/temp#deduct.general-8

Comment: @Barry I don't see anything there suggesting that it applies during constraint checking. "The substitution occurs in all types and expressions that are used in the function type and in template parameter declarations." A requires-expression usually doesn't occur in such places.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, nothing in the content of the stuff you interact with is checked.  Just the immediate context of the declaration.

In some cases with decltype the non immediate context of some constructs is checked, but any errors remain hard.

This was done (way back) to reduce the requirements on compilers.  Only in what is known as "immediate context"  do the compilers need to be able to cleanly back out when they see an error and continue compiling.

Static assert is never suitable for this purpose.  Static assert, if hit, ends the compilation.

Answer (score 1):

I was too stumped by the realization, that I can't control the compilation flow by using static_assert. A limited workaround that I figured out, is by changing return type based on `constexpr if`, and instead of asserting immediately in the function, asserting the presence of a generally unacceptable type outside the function. For example:

```
class Unsupported {};

template<class T>
concept Valid = requires (T instance) {
   {instance.Bar()} -> !same_as<Unsupported>;
};

// Any Foo that has a Bar() method returning Unsupported will be invalid
template<bool VALID>
struct Foo {
   auto Bar() {
      if constexpr (!VALID) // Equivalent to an assertion condition
         return Unsupported {}; // Makes Bar() not Valid

      // Bar() is valid, return whatever you need, or just return nothing (void)
      return;
   }
};

static_assert(    Valid<Foo<true>>, "Should be valid");
static_assert(not Valid<Foo<false>>, "Should be invalid");
```

This, however, is unaplicable to constructors, because their return type can't be changed. Future compiler developers might mitigate this problem, by returning some internal and checkable invalid type, if a constructor/function static_asserts.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid the static assert (that is expected to end compilation) then you need to provide an alternative.
Once the concept is designed, create a variant for the not (!) of that concept:

```cpp
#include <tuple>
#include <variant>

template <std::size_t I, class T>
requires (I >= 0) && (I < std::tuple_size_v<T>)
using Type = std::tuple_element_t<I, T>;

template <class T>
concept has_element_0 = requires {
    typename Type<0, T>;
};

bool test1()
{
    return has_element_0<std::tuple<int>>;  // true
}

bool test2()
{
    return has_element_0<std::tuple<>>;     // false
}

template <std::size_t I, class T>
requires (I >= 0) && (I < std::tuple_size_v<T>)
std::tuple_element_t<I, T> myGet_impl(const T& tup) {
    return get<I>(tup);
}

template <class T>
concept alt_has_element_0 = requires (T tup) {
    myGet_impl<0>(tup);
};

template <class T>
auto myGet0();

template <class T>
requires (alt_has_element_0<T>)
auto myGet0(const T& tup)
{
    return myGet_impl<0, T>(tup);
}

auto test3()
{
    std::tuple<int> X{7};
    return myGet0(X);  // true
}

template <class T>
requires (!alt_has_element_0<T>)
auto myGet0(const T& tup)
{
    return std::monostate{};
}

auto test4()
{
    std::tuple<> X;
    return myGet0(X);  // true
}
```

see it [here](https://godbolt.org/z/YKnP38P4b);

Notice for `test4()` to compile, the code above defiles what to do if we do not fulfill the requirements of the concept. I stole `std::monostate` from variant for this.